# Get Link to View Attachment in Apex

Tags: apex

I need to get the URL to view an attachment in Apex. In Visualforce, I can use URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, a.id). In this case, I want to return a PageReference from an Apex method that sends the user over to the view attachment page.

I can manually build the link as '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + a.Id , but I'd rather not hardcode that.

I tried using `URL.getFileFieldURL(a.Id, 'Body')` but I'm getting an error: Invalid parameter value "Body" for parameter "fieldName". The [example](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_url.htm#apex_System_URL_getFileFieldURL) looks like it is used on an Idea record (prefix 087). Maybe it doesn't work on Attachment records.

Comment: As I see from g00gle there is no other way rather than hardcode this url.

Comment: In our recent experience we have also eventually "hardcoded" it. Perhaps consider a Custom Setting field instead to make it softer and more manageable?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it, but how about [`URL.getFileFieldURL(string, string)`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_url.htm#apex_System_URL_getFileFieldURL).

> Returns the download URL for a file attachment.

You might need to work back to the entity that has a reference to the attachment in a field.

**UPDATE** This doesn't appear to work in practice. From the [Summer 13 release notes](https://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_summer13_release_notes.pdf):

> We’ve also created a new Apex method, URL.getFileFieldURL that lets you retrieve the download URL for file attachments in custom implementations of Ideas.

So it might be that this method is only applicable to ideas.

---

Otherwise Dynamic apex/visualforce might help, but you would probably need to change from returning a PageRefernce. See [Dynamic References to Action Methods Using $Action](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_action.htm)

Comment: a nice underutilized gem there!

Comment: Hmm, looks promising, but I tried URL.getFileFieldURL(attc.Id, 'Body'); but I'm getting an error: Invalid parameter value "Body" for parameter "fieldName". Also fails with AttachmentBody

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work :-(

Comment: Damn, It looked so promising. Back to the drawing board.