# Apex method to retrieve the download link for a standard Attachment

Tags: apex, attachment, method

I stumbled across an **Apex** method in the documentation recently that would generate a URL for the download link for a standard Attachment, with a name something like *getDownloadLink()*.  I don't remember the System class or what parameters it took, but I'd prefer using that in the backend to hardcoding

> '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+myAttachmentId

Does anyone know where I can find this method?  I made a mental, but not physical, note of its location in the docs... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for getFileFieldUrl from the [URL Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm).

> ## getFileFieldURL(entityId, fieldName)
>
> Returns the download URL for a file attachment.
>
> ### Signature
>
> ```
> public static String getFileFieldURL(String entityId, String fieldName)
> ```
>
> ### Parameters
>
> *entityId*
>
> Type: String
>
> Specifies the ID of the entity that holds the file data.
>
> *fieldName*
>
> Type: String
>
> Specifies the API name of a file field component, such as AttachmentBody.
>
> ### Return Value
>
> Type: String
>
> ### Usage
>
> Example:
>
> ### Example
>
> ```
>  String fileURL =
>  URL.getFileFieldURL(
>      '087000000000123' ,
>      'AttachmentBody');
> ```

Comment: It only works with Ideas as mentioned by Daniel [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/28419/4726)?

Comment: @RahulSharma it works on other types, too. It used to be limited, but had since had other types added. It's a pretty handy method.

Comment: This method doesn't work for Attachment.

If we try to execute it 

System.debug( URL.getFileFieldURL(
    '00P1s000000diCg' ,
    'Body') );

it would fail with error `System.HandledException: Invalid parameter value \"Body\" for parameter \"fieldName\"` . Is there any other way rather than building URL explicitly with  '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + a.Id ? Which attachments does support this method if it doesn't support the standard Attachment object?